# Change in view hooks file name/location in core 8.3.x?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I have a custom module that uses a couple of view hooks, and in 8.2.x I had them in my_module.views_execution.inc, in my module root directory. However, with the update to 8.3, my hooks are not being found. I'm looking at the 8.3 docs, but the [incredibly verbose hooks overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_hooks/8.3.x) page doesn't mention it, and neither does the page with the [list of hooks](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_hooks/8).

So where do my view hooks need to be placed in 8.3 so they can be found?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to get the hooks working again by putting them in the `my_module.module` file. I thought I read about that when I was first implementing these hooks when the site was still in 8.2, but it worked in the `views_exection.inc`file and not `.module` then. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this change so far, so if anyone could shed some light on it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: All the core modules still use *.views_execution.inc in 8.3.2, I wonder if it's the particular hooks that are no longer classed as execution hooks or something?

Comment: I just solved a similar problem but I had it in reverse of yours.

my hook was in views.inc and it only works after I clear cache, for any regular page load, it didnt fire.

I renamed it to views_execution.inc and now it is all back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I just used query_alter in `module.views_execution.inc` in a Drupal 8.7 installation and it ran fine. So there shouldn't be any change for the behavior of module.views_execution.inc location.

The API documentation seems to show the same as well

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.views_execution.inc/8.8.x